How to Retrieve Custom Audience-Specific Metrics (Impressions, Spend, CPM) via Meta Marketing API?
How can I obtain insights like impressions, spend, or CPM for specific custom audiences within my ad account using Meta's Marketing API? While I can retrieve general ad set insights, I need to break down performance metrics based on custom audiences. Is there a recommended approach or workaround for this?
